# Can I exclude onclick value from a tag with xpath query?

Tags: python, xpath

This is my xpath query:

```
'//div[contains(@class,"group") and contains(@class,"group-even")]//div[descendant-or-self::text()]'
```

Result:

```
<div> 
<h3>Online Services</h3> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="https://www.domain.com/shipping/label.htm" onclick="dcsMultiTrack('DCS.dcsuri','/POLocator/', 'WT.ti','Link: POLocator: OnlineServices: PrintLabelwPostge', 'WT.z_section','POLocator', 'WT.z_link','OnlineServices_PrintLabelwPostge','WT.dl','1000')">Print a Label with Postage â€º</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.domain.com/shipping/carrierpickup/welcome.htm" onclick="dcsMultiTrack('DCS.dcsuri','/POLocator/', 'WT.ti','Link: POLocator: OnlineServices: SchedPckup', 'WT.z_section','POLocator', 'WT.z_link','OnlineServices_SchedPckup','WT.dl','1000')">Schedule a Pickup â€º</a></li> 
 </ul> 
 /div>
```

Is it possible to exclude onclick="value" from a tag?

Comment: You can't *exclude* anything using XPath alone. Where do you plan to use this? What languages? Java, C#, XSLT?

Comment: I want to use in python.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I just did it using reg expresion: re.sub(r'onclick="[^"]+"',"",item)